# Android MediaPlayer: render frame from external videofile to texture over background camera frame

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-mediaplayer, vuforia

I'm developing a simple app: it should detect an object in active AR-session (Vuforia UserDefinedTarget), stick a surface to this object and start to render frames from videofile to texture. But instead of video-frame I see the frame from camera in this texture. I'm not sure if this specific Vuforia issue or just wrong setting of MediaPlayer.

Here is the MediaPlayer init:

```
videoPlayer.setSurface(mRenderer?.planeSurface)
videoPlayer.isLooping = true
val afd: AssetFileDescriptor
try {
    afd = assets.openFd("test.mp4")
    videoPlayer.setDataSource(afd.fileDescriptor, afd.startOffset, afd.length)
    videoPlayer.prepare()
    videoPlayer.start()
} catch (e: IOException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

Texture creation:

```
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, planeSurfaceTextureId, 0)
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, planeSurfaceTextureId[0])
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR)
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR)
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
planeSurfaceTexture = SurfaceTexture(planeSurfaceTextureId[0])
planeSurfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(mActivity)
planeSurface = Surface(planeSurfaceTexture)
```

And here is the rendering:

```
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, planeSurfaceTextureId, 0)
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, planeSurfaceTextureId[0])
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR)
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR)
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
planeSurfaceTexture = SurfaceTexture(planeSurfaceTextureId[0])
planeSurfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(mActivity)
planeSurface = Surface(planeSurfaceTexture)
```

I'm new in Android, so it might be some stupid problem, please help me to figure it out:) Probably it could be done without GLES..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you managed to find solution for that?